# Use config.yml parameters in service's tag definition

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'd like to put a class name (which has been configured in `app/config/config.yml` by the user) in the tag definition of my Bundle's service configuration.

`app/config/config.yml` :

```
my:
    class_name: AppBundle\Entity\Product
```

My bundle's configuration : `services.xml`

```
<service id="my.entity_listener" class="My\EventListener\MyListener">
    <tag name="doctrine.orm.entity_listener" entity="%my.class_name%" event="preUpdate" />
</service>
```

Is that possible in any way ? All I can get is %my.class_name%. It isn't replaced in the tag definition. Although, my dependency injection is working as it replaces it well just above, in the same config file :

```
<service id="my.param_converter" class="My\ParamConverter\MyParamConverter">
    <tag name="request.param_converter" converter="user" priority="10" />
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" />
    <argument>%my.class_name%</argument> <!-- Replaced by AppBundle\Entity\Product -->
</service>
```

Comment: There is no way to directly use my.class_name as a parameter since it is not a parameter.  You will need to use a compiler pass to modify your service definition.  Can be a bit involved: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, if I want to add some custom parameters globally in config.yml I do something like this:

```
parameters:
    my:
      - {class_name: "AppBundle\Entity\Product"}
```

Comment: Do you put all the configuration of yout bundles in parameters.yml ? How do you use validation in this case ? How do people who use your bundles know they have to put its config in their very own parameters.yml file ??

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try using `parameters` instead of `my` like this:

```
parameters:
    class_name: AppBundle\Entity|Product
```

And then use it as `%class_name%`

Comment: Same question as for stuzzo above : 
Do you put all the configuration of yout bundles in parameters.yml ? How do you use validation in this case ? How do people who use your bundles know they have to put its config in their very own parameters.yml file ??

Comment: Check out the new comment by Cerad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384214/use-config-yml-parameters-in-services-tag-definition/39385874?noredirect=1#comment66107979_39384214 - this is how I do it in my bundles (but I haven't released any of them as open source - we use them internally at work).

Comment: Also, take a look at how other people do it in some popular bundles. Here you have the [NelmioApiDocExtension.php](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/NelmioApiDocExtension.php) from NelmioApiDocBundle. As you can see - they read everything from config and pass it to parameters at runtime.

Comment: Yes, this is what i also do

Comment: I take the config.yml values in my DependencyInjection and I set them as parameters. And wheni I try to replace it in `<argument>%my.class_name%</argument>` it works perfectly but when I do it in `<tag name="doctrine.orm.entity_listener" entity="%my.class_name%" event="preUpdate" />` it doesnt work anymore. I know my english isn't amazing, but i thought it was clear in my question... As i say "Although, my dependency injection is working as it replaces it well just above, in the same config file."...

Comment: You didn't mention the key word "parameter" in your original question so I assumed you were trying to use config values directly :) I just tested a similar approach in a Yaml config file just to make sure this issue isn't related to XML configuration but it also didn't work. Maybe it's a limitation of Symfony itself, but I haven't found any information about it in the docs. I guess you'll have to manage without a parameter here :)

Comment: Thanks for your time ! I've switched to a classyc EventListener with a `$entity typeof MyEntityInterface` that force the user to implement it in order to use the event. Have a nice day !